# map close parenthesis in vim

Tags: vim, parentheses

Currently I moved to vim to use it as my text editor 
but I have a problem. In my `.vimrc` file, I mapped `{`, `[`, and `<` to be `{}`, `[]`, and `<>` respectively, it works right but vim makes a lot of blank spaces inside `(` to be like `(         )`!

How can I solve that without adding a plugins if it possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your actual code, not screenshots.

Comment: thanks for your answer romainl but i have a problem posting the code in my .vimrc file :( how can i post it ?!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The duplicate doesn't work with Vim 7.4 and the only other answers are about plugins...

Answer (score 1):

Then I start `vim` (or `gvim`) with an rc file with *only* the following commands, it works as expected.

```
set nocompatible
inoremap { {}<left>
inoremap ( ()<left>
inoremap [ []<left>
inoremap < <lt>><left>
inoremap " ""<left>
inoremap ' ''<left>
```

Copy the above for a file (e.g. `foo`), and run `vim -u foo`, see if it works. If that doesn't work, I cannot reproduce your problem.

If the lines above work, then add the rest of your rc file piece-by-piece, and check where the behavior changes.

Comment: thank you very much Ronald i have deleted the content of my .vimrc and typed your code and it works in the way i want although the < produced < > with one space inside :D but it's not a big problem any way ^_^ . Thank You Man !

Comment: Since Vim7.4.849, prefer `....<c-g>U<left>` is order to support redo.